# UILabel Rotation

Tags: ios, swift3

I'm Working on TableViewCell and i'm using swift. As my Design I want a UIlabel in vertical align like "Confirm" [image]

I have set this in Cell class

```
class AppointmentCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var appointmentStatus: UILabel!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    let height = self.appointmentStatus.frame.size.height
    let width = self.appointmentStatus.frame.size.width
    appointmentStatus.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi/2)
    appointmentStatus.frame.size.width = height
    appointmentStatus.frame.size.height = width
    appointmentStatus.sizeToFit()
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

}

But this solution is not Satisfied. This way taking more width in horizontal if i set constraints on width and height that is shrink the world in 3 characters "Con..." If I remove the constraints UIlabel take more space like...

[image]

This Screenshot From Iphone8 plus but on small Device IphoneSE label not showing.

My Question is how can I Achieve Vertical UILabel with correct frame size and constraints? How can I meet with my Design.
I know this is duplicate question there is more solutions on Stack overflow but i have not achieved my solution.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: There's nothing may cause shrinking of the text except sizeToFit(). Also, there's no need to set frame size after transform. Most probably, the problem is about your constraints. Set them programmatically after the rotation is done.

Comment: Frame code is not working so if i remove there is no change in problem. I have set constraints after rotation but constraints not working.

Comment: I created a label programmatically and then transform. It's rotated without problem. Its size and position stayed same. Nevertheless, some default values or constraints of IBOutlet may cause this. Can you add details about your IBOutlet? You may do something wrong in Storyboard unintentionally.

Comment: I'd recommend not using Auto Layout when working with complex layouts like this, it can be pretty buggy. While calculating the label's size programmatically is more tedious, is much more fail-safe.

Comment: I have done this issue using a UIView with fixed width and set UILabel into UIView without any constraints. Its working fine on All ScreenSize... May b That was Constraints Issue with UILabel
Thanks All